# Following up on an old email from a recruiter

Tags: professionalism, job-search, recruitment, hiring-process, follow-up

I received a job offer in late April from a foreign company. Due to the situation with COVID and the fact that at that time I was busy with my final degree project, I was told by the recruiter that it would be hard to schedule an interview, and to stay in touch.

I haven't heard anything else from then since, however, as I have now finished my degree and have been contacted by this company twice before that, I figured it would be a good place to start looking for a job.

How should I follow up for this position?

Comment: What were your responses to them the previous two times that they reached out to you?

Comment: @sf02 The first time I did an interview with them and wasn't selected. The second time, the interview they offered me was too late (I needed to begin my internship earlier)

Answer (score 5):

> How should I follow up for this position?

Do what the recruiter told you to do back in April: stay in touch.

Call or email the recruiter now. Explain that you have finished your degree and are now on the market. Ask if the position is still available (unlikely) and if not, are there similar positions open at this time.

Don't limit yourself to this one recruiter or this one position. Look around and find jobs that you could fill.

Answer (score 4):

> How should I follow up for this position?

To be honest, I really doubt that *this* specific position is still open, as it's been about 4, 5 months since you were given the offer.

Anyways, you can still reach out to this recruiter via email, and ask if by any chance the position is still open or if they have other possible openings to offer.

You can also look and search by your own means if this company has any openings (on their webpage, social media, etc.), so you can perhaps focus your email and ask for a specific position that you liked.

Finally, I suggest you keep your options open and consider applying to other companies as well in case there is no current opening on this one.

Comment: I think they weren't offering me a specific position, but an interview. I know they are involved in some projects I find interesting, so I thought I could ask after those. I think I will reach out to the recruiter and see if they have any offers. Thank you for your answer!